# Exclude Promotion Price Rules from a Category

Tags: category, promotions

I have a Category, which i don't wants to apply any `Promotion Price Rules (both Catalog Price Rules and Shopping Cart Price Rules)`.

Even when i create a price rule and `leaving blank as condition`, so that this rule apply to all the products. For me this rule should also `exclude this category and its products even leaving blank condition`.

And also, Even its have any condition which should also exclude this category.

For a Category and its products, i don`t want to apply any promotion rules even promotion rule condition have or not, I don't want to allow any discount for this category products.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have found out, you can exclude products but only if they are added to the category. We have reported this at Varien because we only use configurable products in categories..but this makes it impossible to exclude products from a certain category because Magento only looks that the simple products.

If you have the simple product in the category, it works..
For us this is no solution because with over 20000 configurable products in categories, you really don't want to add the simple products as well.
To much ballast since visitors only see the configurable products.

We have reported this at Varien and are currently waiting for their response. It seems to be one of the weak points in Magento that they don't have all functions well developed for all producttypes.

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for this? I really need this functionality to work. @KGW, did varien fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For shopping cart rules, under  `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)` add a constraint `Category is not {Category Id here}`

For shopping cart rules add the same thing but under the `Conditions` tab.

You cannot have a blank rule that does not apply to a certain category.

Comment: if i leave the `Conditions` as blank `(leave blank for all products) its mentioned there`, rule applied to all products, but i dont want to apply any rule to this category even i left blank

Comment: Like I said in the answer (last line). That's not possible. In order to make it possible you will have to make heavy modifications to the way the discount rules work. These modifications are not justified since you can just add a condition to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @marius, can you help in where to modify the code? i will try it.

Comment: @Helphin The catalog rules are applied from `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::applyAllRulesForDateRange` and the shopping cart rules are validated in `Mage_Rule_Model_Abstract::validate`. But I think you have no idea about what you are getting into. Proceed at your own risk

Comment: ok thanks @marius, i will try with my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is an idea to add as default the exlusion of the category? Then you don't have to add it all the time, and you don't have to change the code.

So change the template to be in your own admin theme and then just add your defaults? I hope it is so easy.

Comment: Ha...good idea. I didn't think of that. That way you can later add a discount for the "banned" category if you decide you need one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get this done,

the fastest way is :

1. Create an attribute and set it as `"Use for Promo Rule Conditions"`
2. Bulk assign products to this attribute (import csv file)
3. Set an exception to the rule for this specific attribute.